# XML to CSV using XSLT - preserve polish letters

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm converting XML to CSV using XSLT. My output line in XSLT is:

`<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />`

There is a lot of polish letters in XML, that's the problem. When I transform the XML from Notepad++ using XML tools plugin, the output file (not-saved) shows polish letters correctly, and when you click on encoding it shows `UTF-8 without BOM`. When I save it as CSV - excel doesn't show polish letters. When I change the encoding of file in Notepad++ to `UTF-8 with BOM` - it works in Excel correctly.

I thought all this is a problem of Notepad++, but when I transform it in XmlSpy the output file is also not correct, like in Excel.

I wonder if I could add the `UTF-8 BOM` signs at the beggining of the file (from XSLT, not by hand), but all I could find was how to remove them, and I don't even know if that would solve my problem. I'm going crazy with this.

I'm using XSLT 1.0 btw. My encodings in XmlSpy are default, that is UTF-8. Encoding of the input XML is also UTF-8.

Comment: The problem, such as it is, exists in Excel.  If even small projects like Notepad++ can correctly figure out file encodings when opening, it should be embarrassing to Microsoft that they can't implement a functional equivalent in their applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using XSLT 1.0, you can output `&#xFEFF;` explicitly...

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="'&#xFEFF;'"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

If you were using XSLT 2.0, you could just use `byte-order-mark="yes"` on `xsl:output`.

Comment: It works! I tried something like this with `<xsl:text>` with different options for escaping, but nothing worked. Thanks!